# Node - Check for Network Connectivity

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js app. I am trying to detect connectivity. I know how to check to see if I can reach the internet by pinging Google. However, I'm curious if there's a way to check to see if I'm connected to a network (i.e. a router) before checking to see if I can access the outside world.

Is there a way I can check to see if I'm connected to a network, but not necessarily get to the outside world? If so, how?

I know in JavaScript, I could check the `navigator.onLine` property. However, the `navigator` property doesn't exist in Node.

Comment: Here's more convenient answer by me [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270902/check-for-internet-connectivity-in-nodejs/55536283#55536283](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270902/check-for-internet-connectivity-in-nodejs/55536283#55536283)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess your best bet will involve `os.networkInterfaces()`, as described in the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces):

> The os.networkInterfaces() method returns an object containing only
>   network interfaces that have been assigned a network address.
>
> Each key on the returned object identifies a network interface. The
>   associated value is an array of objects that each describe an assigned
>   network address.
>
> The properties available on the assigned network address object
>   include:
>   ...
>
> - internal <boolean> - true if the network interface is a loopback or similar interface that is not remotely accessible; otherwise false

So you'll want to look for interfaces where `internal` is false.

Comment: Quick note: while this answer is technically correct, keep in mind that virtual network adapters (VMWare, VirtualBox, etc.) don't report as `internal: true`, at least not on Windows... this makes it kinda tricky trying to find the local machine's "primary" interface.