# Node.js - Recreating navigator.onLine

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js app. I am trying to write a utility app to do some network detection. I'm creating this app just to learn more about Node.

In this app, I want to see if a) my computer is online and b) if it can reach the internet. If I was doing this in the browser, I could use `navigator.onLine`, then attempt to reach a website. However, that's not an option in Node.

I looked at the [OS module's networkInterfaces method](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces), however, that doesn't seem to have what I need. For example, if you go to a Starbucks, you can be "online" but not actually reach the internet until you agree to the terms of service for their network. I've been testing this scenario by toggling airplane mode on my machine. Whether Airplane Mode is on or off, the `networkInterfaces` method returns the same thing.

How can I recreate the `navigator.onLine` functionality in Node?

Comment: Could something as simple as a `fetch` to a URL and then a check on the status code work? You shouldn't be able to get a `200` if you need to auth (in your example in Starbucks) because you won't actually connect to the page. Seems hacky but it may save some time.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of Check for internet connectivity in NodeJs
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270902/check-for-internet-connectivity-in-nodejs

Comment: take a look at the repo: [is-online](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to check whether the internet is available or not.

For this install the [is-online](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-online) module: npm i is-online

```js
index.js:

const isOnline = require('is-online');

isOnline({
    timeout: 1000
}).then(online =>{
    if(online)
        console.log('Internet is available')
    else
        console.log('Internet is not available')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling **onConnected** and passing the call back function which will be called when the connection is established

```
const dns = require('dns');

function onConnected(callback){
    dns.resolve('www.google.com', function(err) {
        if (!err) callback();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `navigator` variable globally and set `onLine` param true or false.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const navigator = global.navigator = {onLine: false};

((navigator) => {
  const dns = require('dns');
  setInterval(() => {
    dns.resolve('www.google.com', 
                error => navigator.onLine = !error);
  }, 1000);
})(navigator);


setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Is online:', navigator.onLine ? 'yes' : 'no');
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go the route of

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('ping -c 1 8.8.8.8', function(error, stdout, stderr){
     if(error !== null)
          console.log("Not available")
      else
          console.log("Available")
});
```

or trying to dns lookup

```
require('dns').lookupService('8.8.8.8', 53, function(err, hostname, service){
  console.log(hostname, service);
    // google-public-dns-a.google.com domain
});
```

Maybe trying to resolve a domain name

```
function checkNameResolution(cb) {
    require('dns').lookup('google.com',function(err) {
        if (err && err.code == "ENOTFOUND") {
            cb(false);
        } else {
            cb(true);
        }
    })
}
```

Really depends on your use case.
Personally i'd spring for dnslookup of a higly avaliable address. But if your behind some sort of dns mask that resolves domains do localhost it might not be effective, which would in turn add the need to test name resolution also/instead. Combine those in a function like `checkInternetConnection()` and you'll be as good as it gets.